# I have to return back an array from a function and print it in the main function but I am unable to print it properly

Tags: c

This code returns the new array to the main function using the pointer, but then as I do not know the size of the returned array , i am not able to print only the required numbers and also garbage values are getting printed, so I decided to print numbers which are not null , but the pointer is not getting assigned to integer and is also not being dereferenced. what to do ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *geteven_Arr(int *l, int r)
{
    static int a[10];
    int o = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        if (l[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            a[o] = l[i];
            o++;
        }
    }

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    int *m;
    printf("Enter the number of elts(less than 10) in array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    printf("Enter the elts\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    m = (geteven_Arr(arr, n));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((*(m[i]) != 0))
            printf("%d\t", m[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That code should not even compile. `*(m[i])` should be just `m[i]`

Comment: return o from the function as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

Because you can only return one value in C, generally this is solved in three ways:

1. Return a struct which contains the array and its size.
2. Put a sentinel value indicating the end of the array.
3. Pass in a double pointer for the array, return its size.

#1 is often the best solution, keep all the information about the array together, but I'm not going to explain structs just now.

#2 works well if there's a clear invalid value. For example, if it was an array of pointers you could use NULL. Since this is an array of even numbers, we could use an odd number like -1. [Here's a demo of that](https://gist.github.com/schwern/a4ff6e728a69a9c0fa9f28e7d5c1f8c6).

I'll demonstrate #3, passing in a double pointer.

Also, static memory is going to get you into trouble; each call is returning the same pointer. Malloc it.

```
int geteven(int *l, int r, int **ret)
{
    // Allocate enough space for the largest possible
    // result. Store it in the pointer which was passed
    // in.
    *ret = malloc(sizeof(int) * r);
    int o = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        if (l[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            // The parens are necessary to tell C to
            // first dereference `ret` and then use it
            // as an array. `*ret[o]` will do `ret[o]`
            // and derefrence the result.
            (*ret)[o] = l[i];
            o++;
        }
    }

    // Return the number of items in ret.
    return o;
}
```

And call it like so.

```
// Store a null pointer in m.
int *m = NULL;

// Pass in a pointer to m.
int m_len = geteven(arr, n, &m);

// m's null pointer has been overwritten with a pointer
// to the memory allocated inside geteven.
for (int i = 0; i < m_len; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", m[i]);
}

// free the allocated memory.
free(m);
```

Answer (score -1):

The primary issue is you are using the dereferencing operator (*) twice. Don't use `*` before `m[i]` because `m` is a pointer that has already referenced to the address of array `a` which was returned by the function. In other words, what you are doing is taking the address of address of `a`. It's a bit confusing I know, but that's how I think it is.

About the garbage value, you can use NULL or '\0' at the end of the array manually.

I have made changes to your program and hope it will help you.
Sayonara...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* geteven_Arr(int* l, int r)
{
    int i;
    static int a[10];
    int o = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        if (l[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            a[o] = l[i];
            o++;
        }
    }
    a[i] = '\0'; // USE NULL OPERATOR
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int* m;
    printf("Enter the number of elts(less than 10) in array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    printf("Enter the elts\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    m = (geteven_Arr(arr, n));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (((m[i]) != 0)) // DON'T USE DEFERENCE OPERATOR
            printf("%d\t", m[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not abbreviate your words, many of us are not natively speaking English. And please indent your code properly. -- Instead of telling about confusion, please elaborate how it is really, thus avoiding and resolving confusion. -- How do you differentiate the valid `int` 0 and your proposed end marker `NULL` (wrong type, it is a pointer) or `\0` (misleading type, it is a character)?

Comment: It is not \0 it is '\0' , it use is provide NULL value . '\0' is different from 0 because 0 is a simple integer whereas '\0' has a special function to provide NULL value . And we use it at the end of the array because every last element of array is NULL so that when you print the array it will not give you any garbage value.

Comment: No, that's wrong. A **C string** is marked at the end with the special character `\0`, but not every array. In this case we have an array of `int`. There is **no special value** defined in the C standard to mark the end of such an array. And `NULL` is a **pointer**. Commonly you cannot store a pointer in an `int`. -- The usual compiler systems implement `\0` as well as `NULL` with the value 0, a cast to an `int` will result in the value 0. There is no difference.

Comment: 1) `a[i] = '\0'` is just a fancy way of writing `a[i] = 0`. [0 is even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero), so you can't use 0 as a sentinel value. -1 would work since its odd. 2) The sentinel value would go into `a[o]` at the end of the results. 3) Stop looping when you reach the sentinel else you'll read whatever garbage is in m (it just happens to be 0's). 4) If there's more than 10 even numbers you will overflow `a`, allocate sufficient memory. 5) Don't use static memory, it is shared. [Here is the fixed code](https://gist.github.com/schwern/a4ff6e728a69a9c0fa9f28e7d5c1f8c6).